# GPIO Configuration for Bit-Banging 3-Wire (SCK, MISO, CS) SPI

Tags: stm32, spi

I have an issue with an SPI connection between a STM32F401RE Nucleo64 board and a MAX31855([Datasheet](https://www.digikey.de/en/datasheets/maxim-integrated/maxim-integrated-max31855)) thermocouple converter board.

I understand the issue around wrong SCK polarity and have already ensured that sampling occurs at the correct timing.  (SCK high as given in datasheet of MAX31855 )
To rule out bad settings on the controller side I wrote a test program utilizing bit banging and verified its correctness via oscilloscope.

If left open, the MISO output of the MAX31855 shows sensible readings. Once connected to the corresponding pin of the controller (PC11, in my test program set to GPIO Input with no pull), the signal is squelched. The controller is reading only zeroes and similarily the oscilloscope indicates no activity on the MISO line either). As if the GPIO was set to output at a low level, but I verified many times that it is indeed an input.

I worked around this by inserting a HW221 level converter with a resistor as shown below.

[image: SPI Wiring diagram with HW211 Level converter]

My suspicion is that I made some kind of configuration error on the GPIO pins utilized - are these settings sane?

[image: GPIO Settings]

**Update 1**

Following code drives the SPI, I don't believe this is at fault since I can get proper communication iff connected as shown in the drawing.

```
void MAX31855Driver::DelaySPI()
{
    volatile uint16_t cnt = 2048;
    while (--cnt) {}
    return;
}


uint32_t MAX31855Driver::ReadSPI()
{
    int32_t dataBuffer = 0;


    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(m_pSCK_GPIO_Port, m_iSCK_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    HAL_Delay(1);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(m_pSS_GPIO_Port, m_iSS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    HAL_Delay(1);

    for(uint8_t i=0;i<32;i++)
    {
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(m_pSCK_GPIO_Port, m_iSCK_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
        DelaySPI();
        dataBuffer <<= 1;
        GPIO_PinState misoState = HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(m_pMISO_GPIO_Port, m_iMISO_Pin);
        if (misoState == GPIO_PIN_SET)
        {
            dataBuffer |= 1;
        }
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIO_HEAT_GPIO_Port, GPIO_HEAT_Pin, misoState);
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(m_pSCK_GPIO_Port, m_iSCK_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        DelaySPI();
    }

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(m_pSS_GPIO_Port, m_iSS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIO_HEAT_GPIO_Port, GPIO_HEAT_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    DelaySPI();
    return dataBuffer;
}
```

**Update 2**

I just realized that the level shifter can be removed as long as the 2.2kOhm resistor between controller and MAX31855 is in place. See below screen caps, they show the differece if the dashed connection is placed to shortcut the resistance. To verify the actual reading of my controller is correct, the data read from miso is echoed to a different output pin.

[image: SPI Wiring new]

SPI works if a resistor is in place
[image: SPI Working with resistor]

SPI not working if the resistor is short-circuited.
[image: SPI Not working without resistor]

Any ideas why this setup requires a 2.2kOhm series resistance in front of a high-ohm input? I checked the controller's input pin with a multimeter and it has several hundred kOhm both towards GND and 3V3.

Comment: You have a MAX31855 "dev module", which exact module it is and do you have schematics for it? Why you use a 3v3 to 5v level shifter between two 3.3v devices? It is fortunate that PC11 is 5V tolerant, otherwise there might have been damage. How do you control SS and how much is SPI clock speed? Please show code.

Comment: The module is no-branded china equipment; The board implements the reference schematic as contained in the datasheet.

Comment: That does not tell much to anyone. Is there a regulator onboard? Any resistors? Diodes? Or really just the capacitor? Post a photo of it?

Comment: Yes, nothing but the 0.1uF (supposedly) cap between Vcc and GND. It is basically only a SMD-To-Pinheader adapter PCB. SPI speed is very low, 600hz approx. Inserting the level shifter was a thoughtful process; I understand that the controller is 3.3v but I wanted to see if the level converter input could be driven by the MAX - which is the case. Of course, I'd prefer not having it in the circuit.

Comment: Maybe it wasn't clear, but of course I ensured that all outgoing signals are generated properly (SCK, SS). I just did not include them in the scope screencaps to prevent clutter.

Comment: I see no problems in code or how they are connected on schematics (except the level shifter should be removed). I would double check the supply and ground connections, how is the wiring between devices in practice? A photo of that?

Comment: Wiring is convoluted (its a bigger prototype) and will likely not help much, but I checked all wires for contact (multimeter) and also short circuits to neighbouring pins. I also checked the input of the controller for resistance, several hundred KOhm both towards GND and 3v3, this seems to be fine. If the code and settings are deemed fine I'd beginning to suspect a counterfeit chip. Probably will order a brand model and compare.

Comment: Aha, long and convoluted wiring is important fact. Bad/long wiring may cause fast signal edges to ring, and the chip might understand a ringing clock edge as multiple clock edges which messes up the comms.

Comment: SPI has four modes, determined by the configurations of clock polarity (you mentioned that) and clock **phase**. Could be the issue...

Comment: @Sim Son True, but this is probably a wording issue where I did not express myself well enough. There's a diagram in the datasheet indicating valid output levels and (this is the reason I switched to bit-banging) I am sampling at the correct time just before driving SCK low. In addition, I verified all three lines on a scope, and all signals are as required (CS going low, SCK starting LOW, etc.). It is only a matter that the MAX31855 does not correctly drive its output line.

Comment: I believe the correct phrase is 1-Edge SPI, outputs change when driving SCK low.

Comment: You're having two problems, right? Problem 1: you don't get readings without HW221. Problem 2: you don't get readings when using the STM32's SPI hardware. Is that correct?

Comment: @Sim Son Thats mostly correct. I did the bit-banging example to determine the correct HW settings for SPI; But then even the bit-banging example failed to perform and I am currently trying to get a working hardware setup.